# React:TypeError: can't convert null to object

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm following a course by Max on udemy. But I get this error which is complaining about the converting null to objecct, which I couldn't understand what the error is point to. Can anyone tell me please how I can fix this error.

This is the file that issue the error:

```
    import React from 'react';

import classes from './Burger.css';
import BurgerIngredient from './BurgerIngredient/BurgerIngredient';

const burger = ( props ) => {
    console.log(props);
    let transformedIngredients = Object.keys( props.ingredients )
        .map( igKey => {
            return [...Array( props.ingredients[igKey] )].map( ( _, i ) => {
                return <BurgerIngredient key={igKey + i} type={igKey} />;
            } );
        } )
        .reduce((arr, el) => {
            return arr.concat(el)
        }, []);
    if (transformedIngredients.length === 0) {
        transformedIngredients = <p>Please start adding ingredients!</p>;
    }
    return (
        <div className={classes.Burger}>
            <BurgerIngredient type="bread-top" />
            {transformedIngredients}
            <BurgerIngredient type="bread-bottom" />
        </div>
    );
};

export default burger;
```

[image]

Database default value
[image]

Comment: `let transformedIngredients = props.ingredients && Object.keys( props.ingredients )`

Comment: thanks omar. Now it jumps to the next line, and issuing error there: TypeError: transformedIngredients is null      if (transformedIngredients.length === 0) {

Comment: I assume `props.ingredients` is undefined or an empty object. Did you checked its value?

Comment: so i think you should enable the burger component if ingredients is falsy like null, and then you dont have do check every time with condition... 
you also can add condition like `if (transformedIngredients && transformedIngredients.length === 0) {`
and in the return `{transformedIngredients && transformedIngredients}`